# Hide/show specific emails in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Is it there anyway in Thunderbird to hide/show, for instance in Inbox, quickly with some shortcut or somehow, emails tagged with some concrete tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can use : **CTRL+SHIFT+F**, then select in left "labels" and in right select what You looking for. 
At the end click "save as search folder"

Comment: This opens my search, but no option for labels.

Comment: maybe look for "tags" - I don't have english version of TB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Once you tag an email by a tag given to you (it will then change to the color of your tag) (or if you star it) you can then filter by that tag.

If you need to hide only a few emails, you'll have to tag all your emails with a tag, then untag the ones you don't want to see, and you'll have to create a rule that automatically tags new emails.

To quickly tag all messages, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then from the mail toolbar, press <kbd>Tag</kbd> and choose the tag you want to use from the drop down menu, such as Personal.

Then from the filter message toolbar, press tag to filter on tagged messages.